# Next and/or previous post content

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, content, next-post-link, previous-post-link

How can I show the content in next or previous post?

For example, I use this to display the next post link with title:

```
   <div class="alignleftfp">
    <?php next_post_link('%link', '%title'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="alignrightfp">
    <?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title'); ?>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to show the content of that post (100 Words)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`get_adjacent_post` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post).

It takes three paramters, all of which are optional:

- a boolean, whether the post should be from the same category
- a string of category IDs that should be excluded
- a boolean, whether the previous (true) or next (false) post should be retrieved.

Hence the previous post, regardless of category can be retrieved via

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
```

and the next via

```
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
```

If successful, the function will return a complete [post object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), hence:

```
echo $prev_post->post_excerpt;
```

should do.